# How to measure performance of a computer science algorithm for an academic paper? Wall clock or cpu time (cycles)?

Tags: united-states, computer-science

I'm a new computer science PhD student tasked with benchmarking the performance of a new algorithm. What is the status quo for measuring performance? Is it wall clock time or cpu time or something else?

I'm running this algorithm on a dedicated AWS instance so I doubt the clock time or cpu time will differ much but I just want to make sure I'm using the accepted method.

Comment: It  depends. If you want to do something innnovative, benchmark it against electricty consumption.

Comment: What do others in related papers do?

Comment: Read the literature to see what authors do in similar situations. Ask your advisor.

Comment: It depends on what the algorithm is supposed to do. In many situations the most important thing is *not* speed but rather how good it does what it's supposed to do, in which case you need a metric that measures this (such as precision, recall etc. for classification algorithms).

Comment: This is not a question about academia. It is a question about research methodology in a specific field. If you do not know what the standards are regarding your research methodology you cannot proceed by asking the internet. There is so much more involved than can be answered in simple Q&A sites. That's why every PhD student has an advisor. You must regularly communicate with them so you can learn the basic norms in your field. Best of luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wall clock time is going to be misleading, as all sorts of things can happen to your instance and your process. CPU time is a little bit better, but you still need to look at contention issues.

If you want reasonable timing:
Repeat many times. Use the minimum rather than the mean unless you are changing variables. Use a dedicated machine, even though it will cost more money. Best for timing is to run it on a few lab machines. Compare your algorithm against a reference algorithm.

In general, the OS and other processes can influence timing of a single process. Interpreting results using a single machine is difficult, as your algorithm on this special input might be limited by CPU, by the interaction between cache and memory or memory and storage, etc. The time is insufficient to find out what obstacle you are hitting.

There is a reason that people have written books about performance evaluation and you might want to look at some of them.